# FragmentManager.getFragmens().size() returns inconsistent size;

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am relatively new to Android, in order to check if the fragment is already in the stack I am getting the list of fragments from the FragmentManager, later iterate the list and check if fragments there then I would be loading that accordingly. Problem is get a NPE when I check for the name of fragment in the below piece of code even after having a null check. Any ideas.... Please help.

```
 if (null != frags) {
        for (int i = 0; i <frags.size(); i++) {
            if (frags.get(i).getClass().getName() == backStateName) {// NPE at getclass while juggling fragments in and out of the stack
                Fragment frag = frags.get(i);

                FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.event_frame, frag);
                ft.commit();

                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

An `ArrayList` can contain null entries.

With the support library's FragmentManager implementation, Fragments are never removed from the list of active Fragments. Instead, [their position in the ArrayList is simply set to null](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/62eb3105e51335cf9074a5506d8d2b220aeb95dc/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#L1305).

Thus when you iterate over the list of active Fragments returned by `getFragments()`, you should do a null check because there is a reasonably good chance at least one of them is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

It will remove all the null entries